# m4 definitions on the command line

Tags: m4

I'am triyng to learn m4 by this linkd http://mbreen.com/m4.html

I have a template:

```
define(TPL, World)

Hello TPL
```

When I calling `m4 -D TPL=foo template.m4` it outputs `Hello World` which I not quite understand because when I call `m4 -D TPL=123 template.m4` it outputs as expected `Hello 123`.

I this expected behaviour? I cannot find anything about this in the guide or in man pages

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behaviour. Explanations: if you add `-D TPL=foo` your `m4` file will be:

```
define(foo, World)
Hello foo
```

Please notice the `TPL` changed in `define` too!

If you use `TPL=123` the `define(123, World)` isn't valid because the valid `m4`-macro names are `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` so should begin with a letter or an underscore - and can't begin with number.